# Pandas: Find frequency and probability for each unique row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a DataFrame of categorical data, like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x":["cat","dog","panda","panda","cat","panda"],
    "y":["banana","pear","pear","pear","banana","pear"],
    "z":["france","canada","usa","usa","france","usa"]
})
```

**Example data:**

```
    x       y       z
0   cat     banana  france
1   dog     pear    canada
2   panda   pear    usa
3   panda   pear    usa
4   cat     banana  france
5   panda   pear    usa
```

I'm trying to add a new column, without grouping the rows, which gives the frequency of the row (i.e., how many times that exact combination of categorical variables occurs in the whole dataset).

So in this case, the value for row `0` would be 2, since `"cat" & "banana" & "france"` occurs twice. The value for row `1` would be 1 since that combination only occurs once, and so on, to get the following:

**Desired outcome:**

```
    x       y       z        freq
0   cat     banana  france   2
1   dog     pear    canada   1
2   panda   pear    usa      3
3   panda   pear    usa      3
4   cat     banana  france   1
5   panda   pear    usa      3
```

I can get the values for each of the combinations by using a `groupby`, for example:

```
df.groupby(["x","y","z"]).size().reset_index(name="freq")
```

But this obviously groups the rows together, which is not what I want:

**Best I could do:**

```
    x       y       z        freq
0   cat     banana  france   2
1   dog     pear    canada   1
2   panda   pear    usa      3
```

Thanks in advance for any guiance!

Comment: Use `transform` on any column: `df['freq'] = df.groupby(['x','y','z'])['z'].transform('size')`

Comment: When you say that you dont want to group the rows, does that mean that you dont want the output format of the groupby function, because it does not match exactly your desired output?